# error: package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.env does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow

- I have clone a repo from github while doing the gradle build I am facing the below error.

```
android\app\src\main\java\org\tensorflow\lite\examples\detection\CameraActivity.java:53: error: package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.env does not exist
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.env.ImageUtils;
```

- Code for `CameraActivity.java` causing error

```
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.env.ImageUtils;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.env.Logger;
```

- **SOLUTION**
- The issue was not having the `env` folder. I downloaded the tensorflow code again from the tensorflow github repo and copy pasted the env folder and it is working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of community providing solution here

> The issue was not having the `env` folder. I downloaded the tensorflow
> code again from the tensorflow github repo and copy pasted the `env`
> folder and it is working perfectly fine now  (paraphrased from Lav Sharma)